# Electric potential derivation

Tags: electric-fields

The definition of electric potential is the work done per unit charge in moving the charge from infinity to that distance.

Now from Coulomb's law $f=\frac{KQ_1Q_2}{r^2}$

So we can now rearrange for the electric field strength.

$\frac{F}{Q_1}=\frac{KQ_2}{r^2}$

The next bt is where my confusion lies. To get the electric potential equation we clearly have to multiply by r to get F x R=W. But is this not the distance away from the charge and so the work done in moving the charge through that distance as opposed to the distance from infinity?

Answer (score 2):

For a constant force, we can obtain the work by multiplying the force by the distance it is applied over.

If we however have a non-constant force, then the work is $W = \int \vec{F} d\vec{s}$.
In your case, this translates to $W = - \int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{KQ_2}{r'^2} dr'={\frac{KQ_2}{r'}}|^r_{\infty}=\frac{KQ_2}{r}$.

So the fact that you obtain the right answer needs to be called chance because you are not calculating your work correctly.

Comment: Ah I see so. The easiness of what appeared to be the correct derivation drew me in too much!

Answer (score 1):

In general, the work done by a force ${\bf F}$ is

$$
W_{ab} = \int_a^b {\rm d}{\bf l}\cdot {\bf F}
$$

The expression $W = RF$ is only true if the force is constant, which is not the case here. As a matter of fact, the work in bringing the particle from infinity to a distance $r$ is

$$
W = \int {\rm d}{\bf l}\cdot \frac{kQq}{r^2}\hat{\bf r} = \int_{r}^{+\infty}{\rm d}{r}\frac{kQq}{r^2}= \frac{kQq}{r}
$$

Comment: so is it just a coincidence that it looks like my derivation?

Comment: @JakeRose You can think of this as moving the charge by small amounts $dr$, and them adding them all up. You're missing that part

Comment: I have not reached the level of these type of integrals so it is confusing me slightly

Answer (score 0):

lectric potential is the work done in moving a unit charge from infinity to a point in an electric field. Electric potential due to point charge: V = − ∫ ⃗ E ⋅ d ⃗ s V=−∫E→⋅ds→ V = − ∫ E ⋅ d s c o s ϑ V=−∫E⋅dscosϑ if the stationary charge is positive and if the test charge is is moved from infinity to point P then V = − ∫ E ⋅ d s c o s 180 V=−∫E⋅dscos180 V = − K Q ∫ 1 r 2 d s c o s 180 V=−KQ∫1r2dscos180

Reference https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/derivation-of-electric-potential-due-to-point-charge.528528/